# counter method not incrementing

Tags: java, class, counter, increment

I'm doing an exercise where my main program looks like this and it uses a counter class in order to print a list of numbers until it reaches the limit I give when I create the object and then returns to 0. 
I'm expecting it to return 0,1,2,3,4,5 and then loop back to 0 but all it does it give me 0's.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    BoundedCounter counter = new BoundedCounter(5);
    System.out.println("value at start: "+ counter);

    int i = 0;
    while (i< 10) {
        counter.next();
        System.out.println("Value: "+counter);
        i++;
    }
  } 
}
```

And my BoundedCounter class looks like this;

```
public class BoundedCounter {
  private int value;
  private int upperLimit;

  public BoundedCounter(int Limit) {
     upperLimit = Limit;
  }
  public void next(){
    if (this.value <= upperLimit) {
        this.value+=1;
    }
      this.value = 0;
  }
   public String toString() {
     return "" + this.value;
  }

}
```

Comment: Your `next` method *always* sets `value` to 0

Comment: Try debugging your program to see which line is `this.value` set to `0` in `next` method.

Comment: (note: This is not Python. You don't need `this.` most of the time.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an `else`:

```
if (this.value <= upperLimit) {
    this.value+=1;
} else {
    this.value = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put `this.value = 0` in an **else statement** since it is being executed every time.

Modified code:

```
public void next(){
    if (this.value <= upperLimit) {
        this.value+=1;

    }
    else
        this.value = 0;
}
```